# Git on Mac: How to set Nano as the default text editor?

Tags: macos, git, vim, nano

When I'm using Git on Mac and need to do a rebase, the Vim editor kicks in by default. I would prefer Nano – could someone please explain how to reconfigure Git to make it use Nano for rebase?

Comment: I prefer nano too, I am no masochist.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

`git config --global core.editor "nano"`

More information here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: This is manna from cli heaven     

Answer (score 36):

If you want to use nano as your editor for all things command line, add this to your bash_profile:

`export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano`

This is assuming you're using the system nano. If not, edit to suit where your nano lives (e.g. /usr/local/bin, /opt/local/bin)

Remember to source your bash_profile after setting this or open a new terminal window for the settings to work...

Comment: That's assuming you use Bash B)

Comment: You should be able to use simply `export EDITOR=nano`.

Comment: Opening a new terminal window might not be enough to reload ``.bash_profile``.

Answer (score 4):

I just learned a moment ago that there (on OSX anyway) is a file at `/Users/<USER_NAME>/.gitconfig`

```
$ nano /Users/bob/.gitconfig
```

Then you should see something like this:

```
[user]
    email = bob@sandwich.net
    name = Bob Sandwich
[core]
    editor = nano
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = "code --wait "
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = "code --wait --diff  "
```

After seeing that structure, you can intuitively understand something like (ie: `core.editor`):

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Comment: Love the detail here, ty 

Comment: WTF are you doing there? "sudo nano <file in your $home>"? And only for reading a file? To which you've got access anyway? How about... "cat <file in your $home>"?

Comment: If you use `sudo nano .gitconfig,` on the chance that the file doesn't exist and is created, it will be owned by root. Since it is unnecessary, drop the `sudo`.

Comment: @AlexanderSkwar How would `cat .gitconfig` help someone edit the file?

Comment: In my experience `cat file` causes an 'undesirable' scroll event when the file is larger than the viewport, but I think you should use your preferred method of inspecting; using `cat` guarantees inability to edit while observing--part of a well balanced immutability diet. (also I removed the sudo; thanks)